# Prove if $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\sin(n + 1/n)$ has no limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How to prove this fact either using limit definition or by false assumption?

Comment: Can you do it for $\sin n$ rather than $\sin (n + 1/n)$?

Comment: Yeah. Is it almost the same as for $\sin n$?

Comment: Closely related at least. What is $\sin (n + 1/n) - \sin n$?

Comment: Since $n \rightarrow \infty$ it's equal to $0$.

Comment: _The limit_ is $0$, not the expression itself. But how do you show that the limit is $0$?

Comment: $\cos \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1 \sin \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, so i can cancel out $\cos \frac{1}{n} $ and $\sin \frac{1}{n} \cdot \cos n$. And the  $\sin (n + 1/n) - \sin n = 0$

Comment: Good. So you have two sequences, $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$. You know that $(a_n - b_n) \to 0$, and that $(b_n)$ doesn't converge. You want to conclude that $(a_n)$ doesn't converge. Can you?

Comment: @DanielFischer If it converges then i can replace $a_n$ with some number $a$, but since $b_n$ doesn't converge then if i subtract $b_n$ from some constant it will never give $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand

$$\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right) = \sin(n)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\cos(n)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Note that $\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \to 1$, $\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\to 0$, so

$$\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right) \to \sin(n)$$

Also, note that $\sin(n)$ is close to $1$ when $n$ is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for an integer $k$, and $\sin(n)$ is close to $-1$ when $n$ is close to $-\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for an integer of $k$.

Note that $n$ can get arbitrarily close to these, so $\sin(n)$ gets arbitrarily close to each of $1$ and $-1$, so that limit does not exist.

Thus, the original limit doesn't exist.